# Powershell: Open Chrome --> Send text message from Messages.Google.Com to cellphone

Tags: windows, powershell, google-chrome, powershell-5.0

So here is the deal. I have a script that kicks in once the AC adapter gets disconnected, and when that happens I also want the script to send me an text message via messages.google.com.

I am pretty new to PS, and im completely lost when it comes to HTML, so im not sure what I am supposed to look for at the website.

```
$url = "https://messages.google.com/web/conversations"
try {
  $chrome = (Get-ItemProperty "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe").'(Default)'
  Start-Process "$chrome" $url
}

catch {
Start-Process $url
Start-sleep -Seconds 5

($chrome.document.getElementsByClassName("fab-link mat-button mat-button-base") | select -first 1).click() 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

($chrome.document.getElementsByClassName("input") | select -first 1).value = "95******"
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

($chrome.document.getElementByClassName("input-row") | select -first 1).value = "HS3 har mistet strøm"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

($chrome.document.getElementByClassName("send-info ng-star-inserted") | select -first 1).click()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 

Stop-Process -Name chrome
}
```

[image: Here the script needs to press Start Chat (Start en chat)]

[image: Here the script needs to enter the phonenumber followed by enter]

[image: Script needs to paste inn message here]

[image: And here the script just needs to press the send button / SMS button]

No idea how to make this work, hope anyone out there can help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Forgot to add the error message:



```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\PS2EXE-v0.6.1\ps2exe.ps1
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\PS2EXE-v0.6.1\ps2exe.ps1:11 char:1
+ ($chrome.document.getElementsByClassName("fab-link mat-button mat-but ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 0):

The try & catch does not make alot of sense if you use them like that. You can use that to handle ("catch") error messages -> see [About Try Catch Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7).

If I were you I would go the easy way and send myself e-mails instead.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$username = "sender@gmail.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "yourPasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password
$From = "sender@gmail.com"
$To = "recipient@gmail.com"
#$Cc = "YourBoss@YourDomain.com"
$Attachment = "C:\test\test.txt"
$Subject = "Test"
$Body = "To Whom It May Concern,`n`nthe bike is on fire,`nyou're on fire,`neverything is on fire,`nand you're in hell.`n`nRegards, YourSysAdmin"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $creds -Attachments $Attachment
```

See: [PowerShell: Sending Email With Send-MailMessage (Gmail example)](https://www.pdq.com/blog/powershell-send-mailmessage-gmail/)

But you will have to disable [Less secure app blocked](https://myaccount.google.com/alert/nt/1580365276000?rfn=27&rfnc=1&eid=7359276444837422347&et=0&pli=1) in Gmail.

If however you really really really want to send text messages instead, I'd suggest you either

- get a commercial application that sends sms for you

or

- you can find out how to send messages to i.e. Google Hangouts with XMPP

or

- use [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) and write some code to send the messages remotely. There is a plug-in called purple-remote that you might be able to utilize.

If you still want to go for the method whereby you interact with Chrome, you can use Selenium as shown here: [PowerShell & Selenium: Automate Web Browser Interactions – Part I](https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-i/)